# Is DOTA 2 region-locked?

Tags: dota-2

Is it possible for EU and NA players to play together?

Comment: I would imagine one of the sides (EU or NA) would experience heavy latency if this were possible

Comment: @ZeroStack, surprisingly there are no region locks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### There has been an update to DotA 2's matchmaking, which *does* take region into consideration, though not strictly.

Based on [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/DotA2/comments/5nuq0q/dota_2_update_january_13th_2017/), it looks like this was implemented in mid-January.

It's worth noting that this is more of a *soft* region-lock, rather than a strict one. As [this article](http://esportsedition.com/dota-2/region-locking-use-matchmaking/) puts it:

> This, in theory, would lessen the probability that a player in Tennessee on US East would be matched with a player at an internet cafe in Peru. Despite both queuing on USE, the geographical component would preferentially stack the Tennessee player with others nearby, i.e. in US states.

---

Apparently, there is **no** region lock in DOTA 2, despite this being a heavily requested feature by players (mostly NA players, from what I've found).

See [this rant](http://steamcommunity.com/app/570/discussions/0/648814845544201732/?l=finnish), simply titled "Valve, North America is begging you to region lock Dota."

[Here](https://www.reddit.com/r/DotA2/comments/4dzdks/dear_valve_the_time_has_come_to_region_lock_the/) is another post, as well as [here](http://dev.dota2.com/showthread.php?t=188031), [here](http://www.dotabuff.com/topics/2016-02-25-ok-there-seriously-needs-to-be-a-region-lock-lol-has-it), and [here](http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/closed-threads/415607-why-isnt-dota-2-region-locked). Based on how old some of these posts are, it doesn't seem like a region-lock will be implemented.

So to answer your question, yes, NA players can (and apparently constantly do) play with EU players.

*(Disclaimer: The views expressed in these posts do **not** express the views of all North American players by any means)*

Comment: "See this rant."  South Americans, please don't take offense. Not all of us North Americans can handle losing a game :(

Comment: @TimmyJim I added a disclaimer. Better?

Comment: It's was more of a comedic comment but yes.  I'm actually curious if region locking would even solve the issue because there are definitely people within every region that can't play up to the standards of these MLG pros. If you really want to play with good players, form a team.

Comment: @TimmyJim I figured, but some of the posts were quite inflammatory and rude, so I figured it couldn't hurt. And honestly, it would probably just cause players to find a new thing to blame (e.g. hax or lag)

Comment: This answer is now outdated. While there isn't _quite_ region lock in DOTA, the matchmaking system was recently adjusted to take geographical location into account, which has a similar effect.

Comment: @Ajedi32, you're right. Working on an update to this answer, give me a few minutes.